# delayed_job undefined method `to_datetime' for false:FalseClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am using delayed job with the following versions of dependent packages

```
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.6
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.0.1
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.13
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13
```

When I do `Article.delay.create` I get

```
undefined method `to_datetime' for false:FalseClass
```

Same versions on production server works fine
Here is the entire trace

http://snippi.com/s/unswxld

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with rails 3.2.13. I am not sure how its working on the production server. I upgraded the version of rails to 3.2.22 in Gem file

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.22'
```

It worked fine